# How to auto increment mongo db in Spring Boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I try simple CRUD in Spring Boot with Mongodb. I have problem with id number. How can I  auto increment id. [I tried but couldn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469232/9426025)

Is there any simple auto increment way?

Controller

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepo repo;

@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHomePage(Model model) {

    Employee employee = new Employee();

    employee.setId(1);
    employee.setName("deniz");
    employee.setPassword("123");

    repo.save(employee);  

    ...
```

Employee

```
@Document(collection = "Employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
private long id;

private String name;
private String password; 

// getter and setter
```

Comment: Did you see this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384133/641627

Comment: @alexbt That's right. Problem solved when I tried ObjectId instead of Long. Because the collections in  "_id" are unique. No need for auto increment. Thanks for comment and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public long getNextSequenceId(String key) {

    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(key));

        Update update = new Update();
    update.inc("seq", 1);

    FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions();
    options.returnNew(true);

    SequenceId seqId = 
            mongoOperation.findAndModify(query, update, options, SequenceId.class);

    return seqId.getSeq();

  }
```