# Spring Data MongoDB identifier as object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a java class that as the id has an object that holds the actual id value. How can I use Spring Data MongoDB for id generation and identification, and how to define the MongoDB repository?

Example:

```
@Document
class A {
  @Id
  private B id;

}
```

```
class B{
 private String id;
 private String idAppGenerator;
}
```

This throws exception due to the fact that Spring can't autogenerate value for B class.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448921/how-can-we-create-auto-generated-field-for-mongodb-using-spring-boot

Comment: @dassum sorry but it's not the same thing. In that question the question is how to increment. Mine is more how to use a custom object as the id and how to convert when using the find from the spring data repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Spring data repository is created in the following way:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends MongoRepository<A, B>{
//B is the object identity
}
```

In order to autogenerate values for B, an event needs to be created:

```
Component
public class IdentifierListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<A> {

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<A> event){
        if(event.getSource().getId() == null){
            B id = new B();
            id.setId(new ObjectId());
            event.getSource().setId(id);
        }
    }
}
```