# Unable to set MongoDB to autoincrement in Springboot using Hibernate

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

I tried to do autoincrement in Spring boot web application using this link(CustomSequences):

[How can we create Auto generated field for mongodb using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448921/how-can-we-create-auto-generated-field-for-mongodb-using-spring-boot)

but i got this error message:

[image]

I did some research and found that this question has already been as on this web link:
[Spring data mongodb field auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674917/spring-data-mongodb-field-auto-increment)

Please let me know if i can do auto increment in MongoDB using Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't work with MongoDB, it works only with SQL-based databases. You need to use something like [Spring Data MongoDB](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial) in order to work to make it work.